# What's the word for when you implement a variable?

Tags: programming

What's the word for when you implement a variable?

I'm sorry it's a bit of a simple question. I just can't seem to remember the word.

It's not *implement*, *assign*, or *pass*.

I tried reading a few lists of IT and programming phrases. There were a lot of buzzwords but I'm not any closer to the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean *declare*?

Comment: Why would this be closed as opinion based? If the definition of words are simply opinion based, dictionaries would be collections of opinion polls.

Comment: As a newcomer to the site you should have been welcomed and encouraged, not treated rather dismissively. Such a  question would normally be closed because you did not reveal any prior research such as the definitions of the other words and why they do not fit. Nor did you give an example sentence in which the word is missing. But as a newcomer you should have been guided, not dismissed. Those who think your question a matter of opinion may not know the mathematical or computational use of “declare”. I therefore vote to reopen.

Comment: This certainly should never have been closed as opinion-based. Rather, it needs a definition of what "implementation" entails; that would allow people not to guess but to provide the term for the process you describe. You should also show your research, so others don't repeat what you already know. I'm surprised you didn't find *declare* when looking up words relating to variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, the word the asker was looking for is **declare.** See [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)) on the concept of "declaration" in programming.

A quote from the above, with some minor changes in square brackets:

> In computer programming, a declaration is a language construct specifying identifier properties: it declares a word's (identifier's) meaning. Declarations are most commonly used for functions, variables, constants, and classes, but can also be used for other entities such as enumerations and type definitions. [...]
>
> A declaration is used to announce the existence of the entity to the compiler [or interpreter]; this is important in those strongly typed languages that require functions, variables, and constants, and their types to be specified with [declarations.]

Comment: Please take a moment to summarise external resources here. [Relevant post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). There is no guarantee that a future Wikipedia will say what it does now (or even what it did when you posted the link).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Edited; let me know if the above remains insufficient.